# Material selection for plunger to be compatible with pressure seal

Tags: materials, design, manufacturing-engineering, machine-design, material-science

I am designing a jig to insert a pressure seal into a cap.

The jig has a cavity which the cap fits into and then is loaded with the pressure seal which needs to be inserted further using a plunger. I've tried using Aluminium however the pressure seal is sticking to the plunger. Could anyone recommend a material choice for the plunger that will stop the pressure seal from sticking upon removal.

Comment: An image or a drawing would be very helpful to people trying to answer.

Comment: What is the seal material? What is the aluminum surface finish? Is there any lubricant on the seal (a slight film can help prevent sticking)? How often does it happen?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the seal material.